# How to setup I2C on NodeMCU?

Tags: i2c, nodemcu, esp32, lidar

I'm trying to get a LIDAR-Sensor (VL53L1X) working. I connected the Clk-Pin and the SDA-Pin to my Arduino. Then I run the example script ([this](https://github.com/pololu/vl53l1x-arduino/blob/master/examples/Continuous/Continuous.ino) one). This worked perfectly fine. Then I tried this on my NodeMCU. I connected D1 with CLK and D2 with SDA. I added the Pins in the Wire.begin() line:

```
Wire.begin(D2, D1);
```

Now I got this error message:

```
19:36:40.889 -> load 0x4010f000, len 1384, room 16 
19:36:40.889 -> tail 8
19:36:40.889 -> chksum 0x2d
19:36:40.889 -> csum 0x2d
19:36:40.889 -> v8b899c12
19:36:40.889 -> ~ld
19:36:40.957 -> Failed to detect and initialize sensor!
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that my NodeMCU was broken